# How to send my Lumens from Keybase to Coinbase

Tags: transactions, exchanges, lumens

I'm trying to send my Lumens from my Keybase wallet to Coinbase but I'm not able to. I created a new account to send to, but it only asked for a name, then a private message and public memo. I put the public memo code I got from Coinbase receive. I thought that would direct the payment to Coinbase. But, that didn't work. My Coinbase account didn't receive any Lumens. I only created another account within my Keybase account and the money was sent from my original Keybase account to the newly created account. Not to my Coinbase account. Can anyone tell me how to send my Lumens from Keybase to Coinbase? Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I was able to send XLM from Keybase to Coinbase.

In Keybase, select "Send" -> "To a Stellar Address".

- To Field: Coinbase Wallet ID (e.g. `GDQP2KRQGH...`)
- Amount: select amount you want to send (even 1 XLM worked for me)
- Encrypted note: leave empty
- Public memo: Coinbase Memo ID (eg. `2290123456`)

Click "Send" and confirm. The tokens arrived like 2 minutes later in my Coinbase wallet.

If this does not work  for you, make sure your account is verified. If it is, you may contact the Coinbase support for further help.

Comment: Make sure you put the Coinbase Memo ID in the "Public" memo field.  I failed to do so and my transaction succeeded but it hasn't shown up in Coinbase yet.  Luckily it was only $1 worth of XLM so it's not that big of a loss.  I'm hopeful that the transaction will eventually fail and put the XLM back into my Stellar account.

Answer (score 2):

### Part 1: Coinbase

1. Login to Coinbase and select "Portfolio."
2. Click on "Stellar Lumens" in the list of currencies.
3. Click on "Receive."
4. Note the Address and XLM Memo.

### Part 2: Keybase

1. In your Keybase client, select "Wallet."
2. Select the "Send" button; a drop-down menu will appear.

[image: The Keybase client as it appears on certain platforms.]

3. Select "To a Stellar address."
4. A dialog box appears (above). Paste the Address from your Coinbase XLM page (Part 1, Step 4) in the "To:" field.
5. In the Keybase encrypted note, type what you wish.
6. In the "Add a public memo (on Stellar)" paste the XLM Memo from Part 1, Step 4.

**Important**:

- Transfer a small amount (fractional, even) of currency as an initial test.
- The XLM Memo *changes with each transfer*--do not try to reuse it.