keybase/coinbase
How can I export xlm from keybase to coinbase?
Keybase app says,  "Stellar transactions are no longer supported in keybase app", "Please export your stellar balances to alternative wallets using your secret keys"
However, there are no options (that I can see) to export wallet!
Additionally, I have tried to within coinbase to "receive", and that too was a dead end.
I appreciate any guidance, preferably step-by-step on how to make this happen!
Thank you!

Does this answer your question? https://stellar.stackexchange.com/q/4065/683

Unfortunately no, this does not answer my question. The 2 answers provided were apparently workable in 2020.   Keybase has since removed (I'm not sure when) the option to "send" Lumen.

I think this blog post should help:
How to Extract Stellar Lumens from Keybase

Please post the relevant parts from that link here.  Answers consisting only of links are not particularly helpful and are liable to be deleted.
